# Android: how to convert whole ImageView to Bitmap?

Tags: android, image, bitmap, screen, imageview

I have my application that is displaying images with different ratio, resized inside (centerInside) imageView. What I need is to create bitmap from the ImageView including the background (black in this case).

So for example I have device screen 320x480, full screen imageView with image resized to 280x480. How could I get 320x480 bitmap from it?

On top of this imageview I have some logos or buttons that I don't want to include to bitmap, they're like on top layer. All I need is bitmap with image and black border from some sides.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable();
Bitmap bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();
```

Comment: It gives the size of image but that's not the problem. I need some fast way to create bitmap along with black border. Here I guess I have to calculate the orientation and middle of the image and both black borders to add them manually to bitmap created from the image.

Comment: Definitely the best solution, if you want to get the actual contents of an ImageView and not just the visible parts.

Comment: Note that imageView.getDrawingCache() will get the actual bitmap representation,the bitmap would be lost when the cache is cleared.

Comment: @Cristian m using your code to convert imageview to bitmap, and on button click i want to set that bitmap on surfaceview can you guide me how to do this, when i set bitmap on surfaceview it opens up a black screen. How to handle this

Comment: `VectorDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable`

Answer (score 98):

You could just use the imageView's image cache. It will render the entire view as it is layed out (scaled,bordered with a background etc) to a new bitmap.

just make sure it built.

```
imageView.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap bmap = imageView.getDrawingCache();
```

there's your bitmap as the screen saw it.

Comment: Sounds good but it just pops the crit with NullPointerException. It's because the image is not built yet?

Comment: Ok, along with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2339429/android-view-getdrawingcache-returns-null-only-null it solved my problem :) Thanks.

Comment: The documentation states `buildDrawingCache()` should be folloed by a call to `destroyDrawingCache` (see here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#buildDrawingCache%28boolean%29)

Comment: It is deprecated.

Comment: Yep at this point there is no more need for the drawing cache. This answer didn't age well :)

Answer (score 4):

Just thinking out loud here (with admittedly little expertise working with graphics in Java) maybe something like this would work?:

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageview);
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(iv.getWidth(), iv.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
iv.draw(canvas);
```

Out of curiosity, what are you trying to accomplish? There may be a better way to achieve your goal than what you have in mind.

Comment: I need to slice whole screen and want to have black edges when there is for example only half image on tile + I want to have image centered on screen. Canvas brings back some bad J2ME memories :D

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding...are you just wanting to tile the image? You can define a bitmap drawable in XML that will tile itself automatically. I don't exactly understand what you're asking.

Comment: I want to slice images to squares (i.e. 50x50) including the black background. Images have different colors/ratios. I thought fast way would be create bitmap from whole ImageView, not only the image content.

Answer (score 3):

This is a working code

```
imageView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
imageView.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(imageView.getDrawingCache());
```

Comment: Its  deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

```
try {
        photo.setImageURI(Uri.parse("Location");
        BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) photo.getDrawable();
        Bitmap bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();
        bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 70, 70, true);
        photo.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It works in Kotlin after `buildDrawingCache()` being deprecated

```
 // convert imageView to bitmap
val bitmap = (imageViewId.getDrawable() as BitmapDrawable).getBitmap()
```

Comment: This line is crashing my emulator.  Bummed.

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin;

```
imageView.drawable?.let {
        val mBitmap = (it as BitmapDrawable).bitmap
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As [`buildDrawingCache()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#buildDrawingCache()) is deprecated, From [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52905682/2289835), we need to get bitmap directly from any android View.

**Example:**

```
fun getBitmapFromView(view: View): Bitmap {
    val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
        view.width, view.height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
    )
    val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
    view.draw(canvas)
    return bitmap
}

fun getBitmapFromView(view: View, defaultColor: Int): Bitmap {
    val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
        view.width, view.height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
    )
    val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
    canvas.drawColor(defaultColor)
    view.draw(canvas)
    return bitmap
}
```

**Use like this way:**

```
//@param rootView is View object which you want to get bitmap
Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromView(rootView);
Bitmap bitmapColored = getBitmapFromView(rootView, Color.WHITE);
```