# how to convert a WebView into an ImageView?

Tags: android

i have a WebView of an html page which shows only one image

http://www.google.fr/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo1w.png

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.fr/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo1w.png");
```

is there a simple way to turn it into an ImageView ?

Comment: Why do you want to convert webview into imageview? Instead, you can load image from web and display the same into ImageView directly.

Comment: ok you are right it must be easier getting the image directly...
how  do i do that ? Do i look in bitmap doc ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
webView.buildDrawingCache();

Bitmap bmap = imageView.getDrawingCache();

imageView.setImageBitmap(bmap);
```

Comment: It doenst seem to be working. There is an error from the emulator.
maybe it is because i m on Android 2.1 .

Comment: How is the error? I have tried this before on android 1.6,2.1, 2.3 and it works fine.

Comment: actualy there is no error. When i run the app on the emulator the image view is just empty, as if  it does not exist.

Comment: I found a similarly answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715044/android-how-to-convert-whole-imageview-to-bitmap/4717173#4717173 and it resolved similarly problem. You should check your codes again.

Answer (score 1):

You can open an `InputStream` pointing to the image URL (using `URLConnection`), and create a `Drawable` from it using `Drawable.createFromStream`. You can then set the `Drawable` onto the `ImageView`.

Answer (score 1):

As per your above comment: `ok you are right it must be easier getting the image directly... how do i do that ? Do i look in bitmap doc ?`, i assume you want to load image from web and want to display the same in imageview, if this is the case then refer this to get exactly: [How to display image from URL on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6407324/how-to-get-image-from-url-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

```
Bitmap btmp = mwebview.getDrawingCache(true);
```

this will return the Bitmap image in webview.

And the bitmap can be set to image view by:

```
imageView.setImageBitmap(bmap);
```