# Android - setInfoWindowAdapter with WebView in google Marker (api v2)

Tags: android, webview, google-maps-markers, google-maps-api-2

I have a problem with marker on google maps api v2.
I would like to customize infoWindows with a WebView:

Here my code of InfoWindowAdapter

```
    mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new InfoWindowAdapter() {  
        @Override
        public View getInfoWindow(Marker arg0) {
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        public View getInfoContents(Marker arg0) {
            View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.info_window_layout, null);
            TextView title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title_marker);
            WebView snippet = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.item_snippet);
            title.setText(arg0.getTitle());
        snippet.setVisibility(WebView.VISIBLE);
        snippet.loadData(arg0.getSnippet(),"text/html", "UTF-8");
            return v;

        }
    });
```

And this is the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_marker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/item_snippet"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

My problem is that I see the content into the TextView, but not the content into the WebView.
What i'm doing wrong?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

You can't use a WebView directly. The reason is (source: official docs):

> Note: The info window that is drawn is not a live view. The view is rendered as an image (using `View.draw(Canvas)`) at the time it is returned. This means that any subsequent changes to the view will not be reflected by the info window on the map. To update the info window later (e.g., after an image has loaded), call `showInfoWindow()`. Furthermore, the info window will not respect any of the interactivity typical for a normal view such as touch or gesture events. However you can listen to a generic click event on the whole info window as described in the section below.

You can try drawing the webview on a bitmap (after the content has been loaded) and supplying an `ImageView` with that bitmap in the `InfoWindow` adapter, but you will lose interactivity with the webview anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've tried the code in [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6747701/how-to-convert-a-webview-into-an-imageview but it return a blank image. I don't know why. Can you help me, plese? Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

after a lot of tests, googling and some reversing I can say that view you return in `getInfoContents` is used to render into a `Bitmap` and then hidden. The `bitmap` is then displayed via `GL`

I've found a workaround that can be fine for you.

```
private View mGhost;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mGhost = new View(this);
    mGhost.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(0, 0));
    mGhost.setVisibility(View.GONE);        

    ....
}

public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) // or whatever
{
    map.setInfoWindowAdapter(new InfoWindowAdapter()
    {
        @Override
        public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker)
        {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public View getInfoContents(final Marker marker)
        {
            WebView webview = new WebView(MainActivity.this);
            webview.loadUrl(marker.getSnippet());
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            AlertDialog alert = builder.setView(webview).create();
            alert.show();
            alert.getWindow().setLayout(200, 200);
            mGhost.post(new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    marker.hideInfoWindow();
                }
            });
            return mGhost;
        }
    });
}
```

in this example I've used the snippet to store the url, It's not *exactly* what did you asked, but it may look similar.

**Edit**: the first version was recycling the `WebView` but it's not possible without some trick to remove it from the `Alert`, this revised version doesn't shows the `InfoContents` box below but has still an issue, when pressed it keeps a sort of state, and it believes the marker is clicked after closing the dialog.

You may use a layout that contains a `WebView` to decor a bit the window

**Edit2**: Reverted to something like the first version, a blank `InfoContents` box shows for bit I'm not sure it's avoidable.