# why webview is not visible in info window of the marker in android

Tags: android

To the webview I write the html5 and javascript,jquery related code.Below code is set the info window to marker.Please tell me what will be the wrong in this code .

```
map.setInfoWindowAdapter(new InfoWindowAdapter() {
                                    @Override
                                     public View getInfoWindow(Marker arg0) {
                                        return null;
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public View getInfoContents(Marker arg0) {
                                        View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.popups,
                                                null);
                                        WebView webView = (WebView) v
                                                .findViewById(R.id.webview_popup);
                                        TextView open = (TextView) v
                                                .findViewById(R.id.open_popup);

                                        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

                                        webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/",objectValue.trim(),
                                                "text/html", "utf-8", null);
                                        open.setText("Open");
                                        return v;
                                    }
                                });
```

here objectValue means Html5 type string

Comment: Kindly go to [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15989891/android-setinfowindowadapter-with-webview-in-google-marker-api-v2?rq=1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15989891/android-setinfowindowadapter-with-webview-in-google-marker-api-v2?rq=1)

Comment: Ok,thanks.how to convert the webview to imageview if webview is not supported

Answer (score 1):

In  google map android info window is not an actual android `view` component.  how it works is when you return view from getInfoContent it basically render the view to image and put that image in the infowindow, so in your case when u return webview map will draw it on image mostly the webview will be empty that time ( it wont get time to load and parse and render html content to internal canvas ) so when map render it will be an empty webview. see the reference docs call it a not a live view https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/infowindows#custom_info_windows