# Save button- Coding for picture

Tags: android, image, save

I have an ImageView in my app, and i also have a button that says "click here to save picture". What the button is supposed to do should be self explanatory. Its supposed to save the ImageView in a new folder in their SD card. I have looked everywhere as to what piece of code can accomplish this. I have found some that are similar, but they wont work for me. If anyone could please help me understand what i need to do, or if they know what code will work, It would be of great help to me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a workflow you could use to get the job done:

1. Upon clicking the button, you fire off an onClick(View) (via XML would be OK)
2. onClick(View) would have to [grab a Bitmap off the ImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715044/android-how-to-convert-whole-imageview-to-bitmap)
3. Furthermore, once you have the Bitmap, [you'll have to save it to the SDCARD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649154/android-bitmap-save-to-location)

Hope that helps out a bit!

Comment: i think i was able to figure it out with your links ninetwozero, and im not getting any more errors, but im not sure if they save succesfully. i dont know how i can check because i dont have an android phone, only the computer emulator, and i tried but couldnt check. thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you'll want to get yourself a resulting `Bitmap` from the image data, and then write that `Bitmap` out to a file.  Depending on what level of access you have to the content that was placed in the `ImageView`...

If you have the raw `Bitmap`, you're done.

If the image was in a resource, use `BitmapFactory.decodeResource()` to obtain one

If you have a `Drawable` of the content, draw it into a new `Bitmap` like so:

```
Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmp); 
drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
drawable.draw(canvas);
```

If you don't have any access to the image content, use `ImageView.getDrawingCache()` to get a `Bitmap` of the visible contents.  You need to call `setDrawingCacheEnabled()` for this to work.

---

Once you have a `Bitmap`, just use the `compress()` method to write that image out to a file as a JPG or PNG.