# Getting Bitmap from TextLayout in onCreate

Tags: android, android-layout, bitmap, imageview, android-bitmap

I am able to convert a `Layout` with a `TextView` into a `Bitmap`, as long as the event that happens **after** `onCreate()`.  But when I try **during** on create, it does not work.

Is there a way to get this to work?  I have tried using `inflate()` in various ways with no joy.

There are various answered questions including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715044/android-how-to-convert-whole-imageview-to-bitmap) that address the technique that I'm successfully using in my code.  But the success does not include employing the technique from `onCreate()`.

[image: Bitmap null during onCreate() but works later]

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private RelativeLayout mTextLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // This is what I would like to work
        replaceTheRobot(); // Fails.  Bitmap is null.
    }

    public void onClickGetBitmap(View view) {
        replaceTheRobot(); // Works.  Bitmap replaces the robot.
    }

    private void replaceTheRobot() {
        mTextLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(sampleRelativeLayout);
        mTextLayout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        Bitmap bitmap = mTextLayout.getDrawingCache();
        if (bitmap == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "The bitmap was null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.v(TAG, "The bitmap was null");
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "The bitmap size: " + bitmap.getWidth() +", " + bitmap.getHeight(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            ImageView imageViewRobot = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewRobot);
            imageViewRobot.setImageDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(this.getResources(), bitmap));
        }
    }
}
```

`activity_main.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/sampleRelativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello World!"
            android:id="@+id/helloTextView" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:id="@+id/imageViewRobot"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Button
        android:text="Get Bitmap"
        android:onClick="onClickGetBitmap"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/button" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`View` is not rendered yet. You can use `view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener` to get notified when your layout is ready.

So, something like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final ViewTreeObserver viewTreeObserver = findViewById(sampleRelativeLayout).getViewTreeObserver();
    viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
        viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
        replaceTheRobot();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: your solution put me on the right track and I was able to enhance the solution to prevent `IllegalStateException` and allow it to work on older Android versions.  Since my edits were rejected, I created another answer which I will remove if you make those additions.

Answer (score 0):

Building upon the `user1779222` answer, if you wish to manage earlier Android releases, you can test run the very similarly named `removeGlobalOnLayoutListener` instead of `removeOnGlobalLayoutListener`.  Also, to avoid the error `java.lang.IllegalStateException: This ViewTreeObserver is not alive, call getViewTreeObserver() again`, you can get the observer again instead of using the original observer.  With those changes, the result would be as follows:

```
    final ViewTreeObserver viewTreeObserver = findViewById(sampleRelativeLayout).getViewTreeObserver();
    viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                findViewById(sampleRelativeLayout).getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
            } else {
                findViewById(sampleRelativeLayout).getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            }
            replaceTheRobot();
        }
    });
```