# How to convert Views to bitmaps?

Tags: android, bitmap

I have two Views (`Textview` & `ImageView`) in the `FrameLayout`, I want to save the image with text. For this, I covert the View to a bitmap.

My xml is:

```
<FrameLayout 
     android:id="@+id/framelayout"
     android:layout_marginTop="30dip"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
     android:layout_width="fill_parent">

     <ImageView 
          android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/text_view"
          android:layout_marginTop="30dip"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
          android:maxLines="20"
          android:scrollbars="vertical"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 86, accepted):

**How to convert View into Bitmap**

```
FrameLayout view = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.framelayout);

view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

view.buildDrawingCache();

Bitmap bm = view.getDrawingCache();
```

Comment: @CapDroid and if i have to get bitmap with transparent background?

Comment: can we do the exact vice-versa of it, i mean can we convert bitmap again into view..???

Comment: you can set bitmap on imageview or background of any view.

Comment: Worth noting that this bitmap can be disposed anytime, so it is safer to copy bitmap into your own, Source: http://arpitonline.com/2012/07/17/capturing-bitmaps-of-views-in-android/

Comment: @NiranjPatel I tried above code but it returns the bitamap with as screen size

Comment: Previously, `getDrawingCache()` returned `null`. Then I found this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4618030/6514270

Answer (score 24):

I used to use the `buildDrawingCache()` method to get a bitmap of my layout, but [I was having trouble with it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30961921/is-there-a-maximum-bitmap-size-when-using-getdrawingcache) when the view was large. Now I use the following method:

```
FrameLayout view = findViewById(R.id.framelayout);
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
view.draw(canvas);
```

Comment: Thank you!!! I was searching the whole week to find a solution to my problem with large view and this solution worked perfectly!

Comment: Thank youuuu.Its worked for large views to bitmap convertion.

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: width and height must be > 0

Comment: @V.Y.  This answer assumes that the view has already been laid out. If it hasn't then you will need to create it programmatically (rather than with `findViewById`).

Comment: what if you are not adding the view to activity? just convert it by reference layout id

Answer (score 3):

Hi you can get a bitmap of a view using the following snippet

```
mView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
mView.getDrawingCache();
```

Answer (score 1):

why don't you write your class that extends ImageView and override method onDraw and put there your image and text, it's more easy

Comment: i tried this but i am getting same image without text.int bw = originalBitmap.getWidth();
  int bh = originalBitmap.getHeight();
  
  nb = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(originalBitmap,bw,bh,true);c = new Canvas(nb);Paint paint = new Paint()
  c.drawText(my_text, 0, 0, paint);

Answer (score 0):

First Of all, you need to add dependency

```
implementation 'com.github.vipulasri.layouttoimage:library:1.0.0'
```

Then Convert Layout to Bitmap

```
RelativeLayout pdfmain;
Layout_to_Image layout_to_image;
Bitmap mBitmap;



    layout_to_image = new Layout_to_Image(AllotmentDoc.this, pdfmain);
    mBitmap = layout_to_image.convert_layout();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    FrameLayout v = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.frme1);

    v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

    // this is the important code :)
  // Without it the view will have a dimension of 0,0 and the bitmap will be null
    v.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
            View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
    v.layout(0, 0, v.getMeasuredWidth(), v.getMeasuredHeight());

    v.buildDrawingCache(true);

    v.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           // Bitmap b = v.getDrawingCache();
            Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getDrawingCache());
            v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false); // clear drawing cache
            Log.e("ss","ss"+b.getHeight());
        }
    });
```

Here I have added a post Runnable thread which ensure the createBitmap method will execute only after  v.buildDrawingCache(true);. v.buildDrawingCache(true); takes few milisec time in some mobile and that is the reason it crash in some mobile. Please try this solution if you face null pointer exception for Bitmap object.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static Bitmap loadBitmapFromView(View view) {
    view.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED), View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
    view.layout(0, 0, view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight());

    final Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    view.draw(canvas);

    return bitmap;
}
```