# Get bitmap from layout

Tags: android

I'm trying to inflate a layout and use that to set a bitmap on an image view. Then, I'm adding that imageview to a linear layout and displaying the linear layout. Here's what I've tried:

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {
    private static Bitmap bitMap;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        LinearLayout l = new LinearLayout(this);

        bitMap = Bitmap.createBitmap(getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth(), 
                getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight(), 
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitMap);
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        View v1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, null);
        v1.layout(0, 0, getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth(), 
                getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight());
        v1.draw(canvas);

        ImageView i1 = new ImageView(this);
        i1.setImageBitmap(bitMap);
        i1.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
        i1.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth(), 
                getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight()));

        l.addView(i1);
        setContentView(l);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the bitMap is not being created properly. Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

Comment: uh, i don't know how much clearer i can get, considering ive put up all my code here. all i want is to inflate a layout, get a view from it, and use it to get a bitmap. however, my solution is not working. so how do i make this work?

Answer (score 28):

Convert a layout to Bitmap.

```
FrameLayout view = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.framelayout);
view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
view.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap bm = view.getDrawingCache();
```

Comment: thanks. however, this gives a nullpointer exception on your second line of code.

Comment: i had used this in my app. it's working line, see this    http://stackoverflow.com/q/7200535/964741

Comment: You need to supply the id of the root view of your layout (you shouldn't need to cast it). Polam's root view is a FrameLayout with android:id="@+id/framelayout"

Comment: My app FC when I use this in on create();

Comment: You don't need to call "buildDrawingCache();" since "getDrawingCache();" is doing it already.

Comment: I am trying to convert layout to bitmap. it's working but listview is not displaying in bitmap.

Comment: How to create bitmap in scrollview ? It always returns null

Comment: @AnandSavjani and @OckhamsRazor; For those who receive **null**: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4618030/5318303

Comment: great solution @Mir-Ismaili

Answer (score 3):

```
    /***
 * 
 * @param flameLayout/linearLayout...
 * @param width
 * @param height
 * @return
 */
public static Bitmap viewToBitmap(View view, int width, int height) {
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    view.draw(canvas);
    return bitmap;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps give a bit of an explanation as to what your code is doing and why you chose do do it like that.

Answer (score 2):

You cant get bitmap on the views or layout is not being inflated.

Layout will only getting inflated after `OnCreate()`

.

1.Get bitmap on `Button_Clicked(View view){}`

2.Or using a `Handle()`to post delaying your *get bitmap*

3.Make sure drawing cache is created using `view.buildDrawingCache();`