# How to add text next to marker icon image using Android HERE map SDK

Tags: android, here-api

I have HERE map on my android application. I want to plot markers over the map with some text ( e.g. marker identity name ). TEXT should be placed next to marker image icon preferably right side of icon.

Option Tried :

1. Marker `marker.setTitle` : It only sets title for infobox, TEXT
   doesn't appear always with icon as required.
2. `MapLabeledMarker` :
       Unable to use this with map cluster. What i found is, you can add
       marker object to map cluster but not MapLabeledMarker.

I'm using 90-days trail HERE Map premium Android SDK. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not ideal or efficient but it may be sufficient based on your use case to create a `Bitmap` from an Android layout which represents what you want: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8120310/275524. You can then create the HERE SDK `Image` from this `Bitmap`.

Comment: thanks for your reply. but it is not efficient as you mentioned and more worse in my case because I am dealing with more than 3K markers on Map.

Answer (score 0):

I Think this snippet will solve your problem.

Create a new layout Programatically like this:

```
TextView textView = new TextView(context);
textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
textView.setText("Centered ViewPin");

LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(context);
linearLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorAccent);
linearLayout.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
linearLayout.addView(textView);
```

Add Mapoverlay on it:

```
MapOverlay mapOverlay = new MapOverlay(view, marker.getCoordinate());
 //dp to pixel
    int paddingX = (10);
    int paddingY = (10);

PointF pointF = new PointF(marker.getAnchorPoint().x + paddingX, 
marker.getAnchorPoint().y + paddingY);
mapOverlay.setAnchorPoint(pointF);
map.addMapOverlay(mapOverlay);
```