# Generating an image from a view

Tags: android, image, google-maps

I'm using the Google Maps API to generate a map with several points of interest.  I want the user to be able to export this as an image - basically a "where I've been" image that they can post or brag about or whatever.

I know that I can [convert my on-screen view to a bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7200535/how-to-convert-views-to-bitmap), but I'm looking for something bigger, maybe even something poster-sized.  Is there a way to make a View that will export into an arbitrarily-sized image?

Comment: I bet that there is the bitmap size limitation anyway, but maybe you could do it in pieces and join it together? You will need to move the map wait for it to load and take snapshot and at the end put those parts into single big bitmap.

Comment: Up scaling the image won't work,so Lukasz idea about basically using zooming in to max, then using the navigate to method to move the map around and then join them together is probably the only way to do this.  Keep in mind that you will most likeley run into severe memory issues if you try to do this on the device, probably best done on the server side.

Comment: maybe you can make a little algorithm that take the screen-shot and move the map exactly one screen doing this repeatedly until you create all the pieces of  the big rectangle of images, so then you can make the poster by joining the bitmaps.