# Null pointer exception while converting layout to bitmap

Tags: android

I am getting the null pointer exception error while saving the layout :

My Code for creating the image is :

```
private void mSavePhoto()
            {
            String str=mGetTime1();
            str1="/"+str+".png";
            Log.e("str1", str1);
            mLinLayMain = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.xLinLayMain);
            mLinLayMain.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            mLinLayMain.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED), MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
            mLinLayMain.layout(0, 0, mLinLayMain.getMeasuredWidth(), mLinLayMain.getMeasuredHeight()); 
            mLinLayMain.buildDrawingCache(true);

                    Bitmap mBitMap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mLinLayMain.getDrawingCache());
                     mBitMap=mLinLayMain.getDrawingCache();


             file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + str1);
            try 
                {
                    file.createNewFile();
                    FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    mBitMap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 90, ostream);
                    ostream.close();
                    if(flag==1) // if Created image is to be saved in gallery
                        {
                            MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(),file.getAbsolutePath(),file.getName(),file.getName());
                            flag=0;
                        }
                    else if(flag==2) // if created image is to be sent as attachment with mail then there is no need of saving it to gallery.
                        {
                            flag=0;
                        }
                    mLinLayMain.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false); // clear drawing cache
                } 
            catch (Exception e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    flag=0;
                }

            }// END mSavePhoto()
```

My xml code for the layout is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/img_background"
    android:id="@+id/xRelLay"
    android:visibility="gone">
    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/topbar"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:id="@+id/rel">
<ImageView android:id="@+id/xIvLogo"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/topbar_logo"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
<ImageView android:id="@+id/xIvBack"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/back"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rel"/>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/xTvComingSoon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Coming Soon"
        android:textSize="60dip"
        android:textColor="#ffff00"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/img_background"
    android:id="@+id/xLinLayMain"
    android:visibility="visible">
    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/topbar"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dip">
      <ImageView android:id="@+id/xIvLogo"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/topbar_logo"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">
        </LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dip">
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView android:id="@+id/xTvLblLineSec"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Line Section"
                android:textColor="#ffff00"
                android:textSize="13dip"
                />
            <TextView android:id="@+id/xTvLblLineName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Line Name"
                android:textColor="#ffff00"
                android:textSize="13dip"
                />
             <TextView android:id="@+id/xTvLblBaseRef"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Base Ref."
                android:textColor="#ffff00"
                android:textSize="13dip"
               />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dip">
            <TextView android:id="@+id/xTvLblLineSec_Col"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=":"
                android:textColor="#ffff00"
                android:textSize="13dip"/>
            <TextView android:id="@+id/xTvLblLineName_Col"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=":"
                android:textColor="#ffff00"
                android:textSize="13dip"
                />
             <TextView android:id="@+id/xTvLblBaseRef_Col"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=":"
                android:textColor="#ffff00"
                android:textSize="13dip"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dip">
            <TextView android:id="@+id/xTvLblLineSec_Val"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="#ffff00"
                android:textSize="13dip"

                android:visibility="visible"/>
            <TextView android:id="@+id/xTvLblLineName_Val"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="#ffff00"
                android:textSize="13dip"
                  android:visibility="visible"/>
             <TextView android:id="@+id/xTvLblBaseRef_Val"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="#ffff00"
                android:textSize="13dip"
                android:visibility="visible"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">
        </LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/xTvLblKilometerage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="KILOMETRAGE"
            android:textColor="#ffff00"
            android:textSize="30dip"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
           />
        <TextView android:id="@+id/xTvMeterage_Val"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="#ffff00"
            android:textSize="45dip"

            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:visibility="visible"
            />
         </LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">
        </LinearLayout>
        <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:background="#ed9043"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dip"/>
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"> 
            </LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dip">
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView android:id="@+id/xTvLblLatitue"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Latitude"
                android:textColor="#ffff00"
                android:textSize="13dip"
                  />
            <TextView android:id="@+id/xTvLblLongitude"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Longitude"
                android:textColor="#ffff00"
                android:textSize="13dip"
               />
             <TextView android:id="@+id/xTvLblDate_Now"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Date NOW"
                android:textColor="#ffff00"
                android:textSize="13dip"
             />
             <TextView android:id="@+id/xTvLblDate_Last"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Date LAST"
                android:textColor="#ffff00"
                android:textSize="13dip"
                 />
              <TextView android:id="@+id/xTvLblSpeed"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Speed"
                android:textColor="#ffff00"
                android:textSize="13dip"
                 />
              <TextView android:id="@+id/xTvLblOffSet"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Offset"
                android:textColor="#ffff00"
                android:textSize="13dip"
                 />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dip">
            <TextView android:id="@+id/xTvLblLatitue_Col"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=":"
                android:textColor="#ffff00"
                android:textSize="13dip"
                 />
            <TextView android:id="@+id/xTvLblLongitude_Col"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=":"
                android:textColor="#ffff00"
                android:textSize="13dip"
                />
             <TextView android:id="@+id/xTvLblDate_Col_Now"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=":"
                android:textColor="#ffff00"
                android:textSize="13dip"
                  />
             <TextView android:id="@+id/xTvLblDate_Col_Last"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=":"
                android:textColor="#ffff00"
                android:textSize="13dip"
                 />
              <TextView android:id="@+id/xTvLblSpeed_Col"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=":"
                android:textColor="#ffff00"
                android:textSize="13dip"
                 />
              <TextView android:id="@+id/xTvLblOffSet_Col"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=":"
                android:textColor="#ffff00"
                android:textSize="13dip"
                  />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dip">
             <TextView android:id="@+id/xTvLatitue_Val"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="#ffff00"
                android:textSize="13dip"
                android:visibility="visible"/>
            <TextView android:id="@+id/xTvLongitude_Val"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="#ffff00"
                android:textSize="13dip"
               android:visibility="visible"/>
            <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
             <TextView android:id="@+id/xTvDate_Now_Val"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="#ffff00"
                android:textSize="13dip"
               android:visibility="visible"/>
             <DigitalClock
                android:id="@+id/digitalClock1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="DigitalClock" 
                android:textColor="#ffff00"
                android:textSize="13dip"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
                />
              <TextView android:id="@+id/xTvDigClk_Text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="#ffff00"
                android:textSize="13dip"
             android:visibility="gone"/>
             </LinearLayout>
             <TextView android:id="@+id/xTvDate_Last_Val"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="#ffff00"
                android:textSize="13dip"
android:visibility="visible"/>
              <TextView android:id="@+id/xTvSpeed_Val"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="#ffff00"
                android:textSize="13dip"
              android:visibility="visible"/>
              <TextView android:id="@+id/xTvOffSet_Val"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="#ffff00"
                android:textSize="13dip"
             android:visibility="visible"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">
        </LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/bottombar"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dip">
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">
        </LinearLayout>
       <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/xRelLayContacts"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dip">
         <ImageView android:id="@+id/xIvContact"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/contact_normalicon"
                    android:visibility="visible"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
         <TextView android:id="@+id/xTvContact"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_below="@+id/xIvContact"
             android:text="CONTACTS"
             android:textColor="#ffff00"
             android:textSize="12dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
             android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
         </RelativeLayout>
       <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">
        </LinearLayout>
        <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/xRelLayInfo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dip">
         <ImageView android:id="@+id/xIvInfo"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/info_normalicon"
                    android:visibility="visible"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
         <TextView android:id="@+id/xTvInfo"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_below="@+id/xIvInfo"
             android:text=" INFO "
             android:textColor="#ffff00"
             android:textSize="12dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
         </RelativeLayout>
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">
        </LinearLayout>
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/xIvStart"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/start_2"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:visibility="visible"/>

        <ImageView android:id="@+id/xIvStop"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/stop_2"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:visibility="gone"/>
          <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">
        </LinearLayout>
       <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/xRelLayEmail"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginTop="4dip">
         <ImageView android:id="@+id/xIvEmail"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/email_normalicon"
                    android:visibility="visible"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
         <TextView android:id="@+id/xTvEmail"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_below="@+id/xIvEmail"
             android:text=" E-MAIL "
             android:textColor="#ffff00"
             android:textSize="12dip"
              android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
         </RelativeLayout>
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">
        </LinearLayout>
        <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/xRelLayPhoto"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginTop="4dip">
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/xIvPhotos"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/photo_normalicon"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/xTvPhotos"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_below="@+id/xIvPhotos"
             android:text=" PHOTO "
             android:textColor="#ffff00"
             android:textSize="12dip"
              android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
          </RelativeLayout>
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I am setting the typeface for all the textviews.

My Logcat :

```
10-10 19:12:34.560: W/System.err(12434): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-10 19:12:34.565: W/System.err(12434):    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:455)
10-10 19:12:34.565: W/System.err(12434):    at org.abc.artc.ARTCActivity.mSavePhoto(ARTCActivity.java:434)
10-10 19:12:34.565: W/System.err(12434):    at org.abc.artc.ARTCActivity.onClick(ARTCActivity.java:343)
10-10 19:12:34.565: W/System.err(12434):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3591)
10-10 19:12:34.565: W/System.err(12434):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14263)
10-10 19:12:34.565: W/System.err(12434):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
10-10 19:12:34.570: W/System.err(12434):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-10 19:12:34.570: W/System.err(12434):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-10 19:12:34.570: W/System.err(12434):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4507)
10-10 19:12:34.575: W/System.err(12434):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-10 19:12:34.575: W/System.err(12434):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-10 19:12:34.575: W/System.err(12434):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
10-10 19:12:34.580: W/System.err(12434):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
10-10 19:12:34.580: W/System.err(12434):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: at org.abc.artc.ARTCActivity.mSavePhoto(ARTCActivity.java:434) where is this line?

Comment: mSavePhoto() is a function which is called on clicking a button. What do you mean by "where is this line"?

Comment: Line 434 is likely to be this: `Bitmap mBitMap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mLinLayMain.getDrawingCache());`.  My guess is that the NPE is happening within `createBitmap()`. You may want to check the value being returned by `getDrawingCache()` as it may be null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanx all of you for quick responses.. The above code works fine for 2.3 but throws NPE in 4.0 and above.. It is because I have set the margin for child layouts due to which it returns null. In 2.3 also once saving of the image is done then the device's screen blinks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling `setContentView(R.layout.viewGroup)` before calling `mSavePhoto()` ?

Your `mLinLayMain` is getting `NULL`.

Check, whether `mLinLayMain`  comes in your current layout file.

Comment: Try mLinLayMain = (LinearLayout)YouActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.xLinLayMain);

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a call to `layout` on your `mLinLayMain` before, because otherwise the view has a dimension of 0,0 and the bitmap will be null.

Change the lines

```
mLinLayMain.buildDrawingCache(true);
Bitmap mBitMap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mLinLayMain.getDrawingCache());
```

to

```
mLinLayMain.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED), MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
mLinLayMain.layout(0, 0, mLinLayMain.getMeasuredWidth(), mLinLayMain.getMeasuredHeight()); 
mLinLayMain.buildDrawingCache(true);
Bitmap mBitMap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mLinLayMain.getDrawingCache());
mLinLayMain.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

which layout we change to bitmap see this here FrameLayout  change to bitmap

```
FrameLayout view = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.framelayout);

view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

view.buildDrawingCache();

Bitmap bm = view.getDrawingCache();
```

and see [How to convert Views to bitmaps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7200535/how-to-convert-views-to-bitmap)