# How to convert View to Bitmap in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I'm using following line to convert view to bitmap in android.

```
view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap b= view.getDrawingCache();
```

I am having value in view when I am converting to Bitmap, its showing bitmap value null.

Comment: You can't do this in onCreate, since the UI is not drawn until afterwards.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: As simon said, the code is right but you must put it in the right place.

Comment: i am doing this one outside of oncreate(),In view i am having zoomable  bitmap value so i trying convert viw to bitmap and finally i am add that one to ImageView.

Comment: try searching http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7200535/how-to-convert-views-to-bitmap

Comment: my view values =packagename.classname@4053675 like this its coming ,so i am try to convert bitmap but its showing null.Help me

Comment: Invoke the code after all view are draw on the screen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Activity Class In this  Class I Convert the Layout(View) into Image.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class ImageActivity extends Activity {

    LinearLayout layout=null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_convert);
        layout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout);
        ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView01)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Bitmap map=ConvertToBitmap(layout);
                Log.v("BitmapObject", map.toString());
            }
        });       
    }

    protected Bitmap ConvertToBitmap(LinearLayout layout) {
        Bitmap map;
        layout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        layout.buildDrawingCache();
        return map=layout.getDrawingCache();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use below code : just replace yourview value

```
YourView view = (YourView )findViewById(R.id.yourViewId);

view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

view.buildDrawingCache();

Bitmap bm = view.getDrawingCache();
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7200535/how-to-convert-views-to-bitmap)

Comment: my view values =packagename.classname@4053675 like this its coming ,so i am try to convert bitmap but its showing null.Help me

Comment: @sravanthi you have to override `onWindowsFocusChanged()` to get a non-null value :)

Answer (score 1):

Try This :

```
LinearLayout view1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear1);
ImageView my_image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.my_imageView);

Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(view1.getWidth(), view1.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
view1.draw(c);

my_image.setImageBitmap(b);
```

Hope it helps you.

Thanks.

Comment: my view values =packagename.classname@4053675 like this its coming ,so i am try to convert bitmap but its showing null.Help me

Comment: You need to initialize your view before using and this will work out side of your onCreate method. Try to call this things on some button click event so it will allow to initialize your view before using.

Comment: I have a layout which I am trying to get the background from. The layout's widthXheight is different from the bitmap's width and height :/

Answer (score 0):

This could work

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromView(View view) {
   Bitmap returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
   Canvas canvas = new Canvas(returnedBitmap);
   view.layout(0, 0, view.getLayoutParams().width, view.getLayoutParams().height);
   view.draw(canvas);
   return returnedBitmap;
}
```

Comment: my view values =packagename.classname@4053675 like this its coming ,so i am try to convert bitmap but its showing null.Help me

Comment: How do you call it from the Activity?

Comment: If you add it to your activity you can call it directly from the activity. You can also remove static from the method then.

Comment: Just need to change this line: view.layout(0, 0, view.getWidth(), view.getHeight());