# How to get a screenshot from SurfaceView?

Tags: android, surfaceview, exoplayer

I'm playing some videos using ExoPlayer and I'd like to get the current picture displayed on my SurfaceView, how can I make it?

Thanks,

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are you comfortable with SurfaceViews and/or ExoPlayer video renderers?

Comment: As far as SurfaceView goes this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27817577/ . I don't know if ExoPlayer has some nifty screen-grab feature though.

Answer (score 0):

If you use SurfaceView, you can not get the screenshot. However you can use a TextureView to play your video, then you can get screenshot from TextureView.

Here is an sample code to use TextureView, on its *onSurfaceTextureAvailable()* callback you can get a *SurfaceTexture*, then you can use this *SurfaceTexture* to create a *Surface* for **ExoPlayer**

```
player = ...

public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
   ...
   player.setSurface(new Surface(mSurfaceTexture));
   ...
```

}

Answer (score -1):

Not Tested, taken from :[How to convert View to Bitmap in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13855087/how-to-convert-view-to-bitmap-in-android)

Changed input param to be more generic.

```
protected Bitmap ConvertToBitmap(View layout) {

    layout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

    layout.buildDrawingCache();

    return layout.getDrawingCache();

}
```

Comment: @Zun Weird, just tested it and it works just fine. What issue did you have?