# Custom view converting to bitmap returning black image

Tags: android, bitmap

I need to create a custom view and then save it to png file into sdcard. Right now I am getting black colour images in sdcard. I couldn't trace out the issue in code. Can anyone please help me out.

layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/address"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
</LinearLyout>
```

In my java file, I have inflated linear layout and set data to textviews and then I am calling:

```
private Bitmap convertViewToBitmap(LinearLayout layout) {
    layout.measure(MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
    int width = layout.getMeasuredWidth();
    int height = layout.getMeasuredHeight();

    //Create the bitmap
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, 
            height, 
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    //Create a canvas with the specified bitmap to draw into
    Canvas c = new Canvas(bitmap);

    //Render this view (and all of its children) to the given Canvas
    view.draw(c);
    return bitmap;
}
```

After getting bitmap I am saving it to sdcard as follows:

```
private void saveBitmapTpSdCard(Bitmap bitmap, String fileName) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 40, bytes);

        File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + File.separator + getString(R.string.app_name));

        try {
            if(!f.exists()) {
                f.mkdirs();
            }
            File imageFile = new File(f, fileName + ".png");
            FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
            fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
            fo.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to get the snapshot of lnearlayout's content?

Comment: @Glenn-- Yes. I want to contents also into the image

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7200535/how-to-convert-views-to-bitmap

Comment: @Glenn-- I had tried this. But layout.getDrawingCache(); is returning null

Comment: Let us see the updated code (your code with the drawing cache method) ?

Comment: Btw, you can just call `bitmap.compress` with `FileOutputStream` directly instead of dancing with `ByteArrayOutputStream` (which you don't need here)

Comment: @DmitryZaitsev I made this change.

Comment: @Glenn-- I got it solved. Check my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got it worked by adding this line:

```
view.layout(0, 0, width, height);
```

before creating Bitmap using Bitmap.createBitmap

Comment: I was wondering why the method is returning null but, good job!

Answer (score 0):

try the following code to convert a custom view to Bitmap Object:

```
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_main_for_bitmap);
    layout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    layout.buildDrawingCache();
    Bitmap bitmap = layout.getDrawingCache();
```

Comment: I passed layout to method after inflating and setting values

Answer (score 0):

The fact that `LinearLayout` was measured by you manually doesn't means that it was layouted (i.e. `layout` wasn't invoked). Therefore children are not getting layouted, therefore they don't receive correct position on a `ViewGroup`, therefore they're not visible.

Instead of trying to mimic drawing lifecycle, I would suggest you to call `linearLayout.post()` on your `LinearLayout` (if it's added to view hierarchy of course) and inside `Runnable` invoke your "snapping" workflow.

Alternatively you can invoke `layout` manually.

Comment: @Mathew so my first thought was correct :) Congrats!