# How to get bitmap from Surface View

Tags: java, android, android-camera, surfaceview, android-camera2

I am attempting to get bitmap from my surface view. I've already seen many answers on this forum and on mostly all forums. I am using a custom class of ViewGroup in which i'm using a surface view to preview the camera image and the Graphic Overlay.

This is my CameraSourcePreview.class

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.graphics.SurfaceTexture;
import android.support.v7.util.AsyncListUtil;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.TextureView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.google.android.gms.common.images.Size;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.CameraSource;

import java.io.IOException;

public class CameraSourcePreview extends ViewGroup {
    private static final String TAG = "CameraSourcePreview";

    private Context mContext;
    private SurfaceView mSurfaceView;
    private boolean mStartRequested;
    private boolean mSurfaceAvailable;
    private CameraSource mCameraSource;

    private GraphicOverlay mOverlay;

    public CameraSourcePreview(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mContext = context;
        mStartRequested = false;
        mSurfaceAvailable = false;

        mSurfaceView = new SurfaceView(context);
        mSurfaceView.getHolder().addCallback(new SurfaceCallback());
        addView(mSurfaceView);
    }

    public void start(CameraSource cameraSource) throws IOException {
        if (cameraSource == null) {
            stop();
        }

        mCameraSource = cameraSource;

        if (mCameraSource != null) {
            mStartRequested = true;
            startIfReady();
        }
    }

    public void start(CameraSource cameraSource, GraphicOverlay overlay) throws IOException {
        mOverlay = overlay;
        start(cameraSource);
    }

    public void stop() {
        if (mCameraSource != null) {
            mCameraSource.stop();
        }
    }

    public void release() {
        if (mCameraSource != null) {
            mCameraSource.release();
            mCameraSource = null;
        }
    }

    private void startIfReady() throws IOException {
        if (mStartRequested && mSurfaceAvailable) {
            mCameraSource.start(mSurfaceView.getHolder());
            if (mOverlay != null) {
                Size size = mCameraSource.getPreviewSize();
                int min = Math.min(size.getWidth(), size.getHeight());
                int max = Math.max(size.getWidth(), size.getHeight());
                if (isPortraitMode()) {
                    // Swap width and height sizes when in portrait, since it will be rotated by
                    // 90 degrees
                    mOverlay.setCameraInfo(min, max, mCameraSource.getCameraFacing());
                } else {
                    mOverlay.setCameraInfo(max, min, mCameraSource.getCameraFacing());
                }
                mOverlay.clear();
            }
            mStartRequested = false;
        }
    }

    private class SurfaceCallback implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surface) {
            mSurfaceAvailable = true;
            try {
                startIfReady();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Could not start camera source.", e);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surface) {
            mSurfaceAvailable = false;
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        int width = 320;
        int height = 240;
        if (mCameraSource != null) {
            Size size = mCameraSource.getPreviewSize();
            if (size != null) {
                width = size.getWidth();
                height = size.getHeight();
            }
        }

        // Swap width and height sizes when in portrait, since it will be rotated 90 degrees
        if (isPortraitMode()) {
            int tmp = width;
            width = height;
            height = tmp;
        }

        final int layoutWidth = right - left;
        final int layoutHeight = bottom - top;

        // Computes height and width for potentially doing fit width.
        int childWidth = layoutWidth;
        int childHeight = layoutHeight;
                //(int)(((float) layoutWidth / (float) width) * height);
/*
        // If height is too tall using fit width, does fit height instead.
        if (childHeight > layoutHeight) {
            childHeight = layoutHeight;
            childWidth = (int)(((float) layoutHeight / (float) height) * width);
        }*/

        for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); ++i) {
            getChildAt(i).layout(0, 0, childWidth, childHeight);
        }

        try {
            startIfReady();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Could not start camera source.", e);
        }
    }

    private boolean isPortraitMode() {
        int orientation = mContext.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
        if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            return false;
        }
        if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
            return true;
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "isPortraitMode returning false by default");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Now when I capture the image from CameraSource it snapshots the image but not the graphic overlay which i'm inflating on the surface view. Neither does the surface view lets me take a bitmap from it. If i try to get screenshot of the root view then it captures only the Graphic Overlay not the surface view image.

My app is working on the logic of a face filter github project(link will be provided upon request)
I'm basically stuck because i want to capture both.

Answer (score 0):

you have to take a particular view screenshot like convert any view into bitmap this way

[How to convert Views to bitmaps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7200535/how-to-convert-views-to-bitmaps)

Comment: I've tried to take screenshot of the surface view. But it only captures the graphic overlay not the picture of person.