# Convert layout to bitmap?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, bitmap

How do I convert the following layout to a bitmap?

I tried using Kotlin's `view.drawToBitmap()` but it only applies to views and not layouts.

```
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: a layout is also a view

Comment: This article might help you . [How to convert Views to bitmaps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7200535/how-to-convert-views-to-bitmaps)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Pass your view into `viewToBitmap(view)`

```
private Bitmap viewToBitmap(LinearLayout view) {
            try {
               // create bitmap screen capture
                view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getDrawingCache());
                view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
                return bitmap;
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e(TAG, "takeScreenshot: Throwable: "+e.getMessage() );
                return null;
            }
        }
```