# Clip part of ImageView and display it somewhere else?

Tags: android, imageview

I have an custom ImageView and I want to "clip" a section of it and then pass it to another activity. I've got the "passing to another Activity" part via a Bundle..but the clipping part has me stumped. I've tried something based on this question: [Android View.getDrawingCache returns null, only null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2339429/android-view-getdrawingcache-returns-null-only-null)

But I still end up with a null Bitmap (I am assuming I need the bitmap in order to then clip it and pass the clip to another Activity..this may be a false assumption). 
Here is my actual code:

```
view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
view.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
view.layout(0, 0, view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight())    ; 

    view.buildDrawingCache(true);
        view.buildDrawingCache();
        Bitmap bmap = view.getDrawingCache();
        view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
        Log.d("IMAGE","HEIGHT: "+bmap.getHeight());
```

This results in a null pointer exception at the last line. Suggestions?

Comment: is your view drawn on screen?

Comment: Yes. At the point this is called, the view is visible.