# android Convert FrameLayout to Drawable

Tags: android, bitmap, android-framelayout

I have this FrameLayout in my LinearLayout :

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/desktopsFramelayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="none"
        android:src="@drawable/accept" />

</FrameLayout>
```

then in code I try convert it in Drawable like this :

```
FrameLayout desktopFrameLayout = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.desktopsFramelayout);

        desktopFrameLayout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        desktopFrameLayout.buildDrawingCache();     
        Bitmap bitmap = desktopFrameLayout.getDrawingCache();
```

the `bitmap` is `null` ,why ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this link and read nininho's answer:
[Android View.getDrawingCache returns null, only null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2339429/android-view-getdrawingcache-returns-null-only-null)

I think this it returns null because your view has dimensions (0,0)

Answer (score 0):

Probably because you just enabled DrawingCache but the FrameLayout didnt had any time to build it yet.

try to assign the drawingCacheEnabled in xml and call desktopFrameLayout.getDrawingCache();

Afterwards it might have the Cache build when you ask for it.

If not try it later in the lifecycle.

Answer (score 0):

```
Bitmap b = null;
desktopFrameLayout.post(new Runnable() {
    desktopFrameLayout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    desktopFrameLayout.buildDrawingCache();     
    b = desktopFrameLayout.getDrawingCache();
});
```