# Nullpointer in getting view

Tags: android, view, nullpointerexception

```
Bitmap bitmap;
View v1 = l1.getRootView();
v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

Doesn't work for me as:

```
bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
```

Is causing a force close.

I'm using a `LinearLayout`

Comment: where did you instantiate `l1` ?

Comment: Perhaps [error taking a screenshot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15748713/) can provide some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the drawing cache, if v1.getDrawingCache() is returning null.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getDrawingCache(boolean)

Comment: OP has in their sourcecode `v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);` so it seems like this is not the issue.

Comment: From the doc:When hardware acceleration is turned on, enabling the drawing cache has no effect on rendering because the system uses a different mechanism for acceleration which ignores the flag. If you want to use a Bitmap for the view, even when hardware acceleration is enabled, see setLayerType(int, android.graphics.Paint) for information on how to enable software and hardware layers.

Comment: I think this is for if you are creating your own view and overriding onDraw `enabling the drawing cache has no effect on rendering` When they say that I think they mean rendering onto the screen, not using getDrawingCache() I have used getDrawingCache() in the past with hardware acceleration on and had no issue.