# google maps marker defined in layout XML

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

Is it possible to define in Layouts folder (Android) an XML file where i specify how my pointer/marker will look like?
For example, i would like to have an image and a TextView as Marker (not the popup, but the marker itself).

I have been using Google Maps Utility Library to use Clusters on Google Maps, but they just have examples how to do it using the normal white marker with background ([example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/images/utility-markercluster-custom.png))

Lets say that i want exactly what do they have, except the white board around.

Do you know how can i accomplish this?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

I'm trying to combine [this tutorial](http://www.nasc.fr/android/android-using-layout-as-custom-marker-on-google-map-api/)  with Google Maps Utility Library (Clusters).
For now i have this, but is not working:

custom_cluster_marker_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:src="@drawable/cluster" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/num_txt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="19dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="0"
        android:textColor="#ce8223"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

MeterRender.java

```
private class MeterRenderer extends DefaultClusterRenderer<MyMeter> {


        private TextView mClusterTextView;

        public MeterRenderer() {
            super(c, map, mClusterManager);

            View custom_cluster_view = ((LayoutInflater) c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.custom_cluster_marker_layout, null);
            mClusterTextView = (TextView) custom_cluster_view.findViewById(R.id.num_txt);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onBeforeClusterItemRendered(MyMeter meter, MarkerOptions markerOptions) {

            markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                    .fromPath(createBillboardTexture("a", "123")));
        }

        @Override
        protected void onBeforeClusterRendered(Cluster<MyMeter> cluster, MarkerOptions markerOptions) {
            View custom_cluster_view = ((LayoutInflater) c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.custom_cluster_marker_layout, null);
            mClusterTextView = (TextView) custom_cluster_view.findViewById(R.id.num_txt);
            mClusterTextView.setText(cluster.getSize());
            markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(createDrawableFromView(c, custom_cluster_view)));


        }

        public Bitmap createDrawableFromView(Context context, View view) {
            DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
            ((Activity) context).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);

            view.measure(displayMetrics.widthPixels, displayMetrics.heightPixels);
            view.layout(0, 0, displayMetrics.widthPixels, displayMetrics.heightPixels);
            view.buildDrawingCache();
            Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
            view.draw(canvas);

            return bitmap;
        }
}
```

Comment: Did you get a chance to solve this issue? if so how? I similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25965799/xml-layout-to-map-marker

Comment: HI, if you resolved this issue, kindly help me. I am facing same problem. I want to display dynamic content like numbers on map marker icons with different colors.

Comment: the snippet code looks good but createDrawableFromView is wrote wrong, you didn't set view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true) http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setDrawingCacheEnabled(boolean) looks this comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2339429/android-view-getdrawingcache-returns-null-only-null/4618030#4618030

Answer (score 1):

You probably already have added `Marker` in your map, so try use `Marker` instead of `MarkerOptions`

```
@Override
protected void onBeforeClusterItemRendered(MyMeter meter, Marker marker) {

    marker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                    .fromPath(createBillboardTexture("a", "123")));
}

@Override
protected void onBeforeClusterRendered(Cluster<MyMeter> cluster, Marker marker) {
    View custom_cluster_view = ((LayoutInflater) c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.custom_cluster_marker_layout, null);
    mClusterTextView = (TextView) custom_cluster_view.findViewById(R.id.num_txt);
    mClusterTextView.setText(cluster.getSize());
    marker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(createDrawableFromView(c, custom_cluster_view)));   
}
```

Comment: It isn't problem in already created Marker but in method (createDrawableFromView) which draw View

Answer (score 0):

You can use your own image as a marker. You can load the icon from sources.

```
fromAsset(String assetName) – Loading from assets folder
fromBitmap (Bitmap image) – Loading bitmap image
fromFile (String path) – Loading from file
fromResource (int resourceId) – Loading from drawable resource

// create marker
MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("Hello Maps");

// Changing marker icon
marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.my_marker_icon)));

// adding marker
googleMap.addMarker(marker);
```

Comment: I know how to define my own icon, but this problem is different. The main problem for me is that i want to have dynamic information on this icon/marker, thats why i would like to have something defined on Layout.xml to be able to access to his TextView (for example) and change it whenever i need.

Comment: I would love an answer too.  When I use a layout, it is blank.  I want to change background colors based on type of marker.  A static image wont cut it.  And I am not making multiple sets of icons to accomplish this.

Comment: Did you get a chance to solve this issue? if so how? I similar issue: http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/25965799/xml-layout-to-map-marker