# android 4.4.2 bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);

Tags: java, android, bitmap

After my tablet update to 4.4.2 my app crashes.

My log says at `com.example.androidhive.EditProductActivity$6.onClick(EditProductActivity.java:344`)

and the line is

```
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
```

This is a part off my code (the bitmap code)

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    btn_shoot.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);                        


                            View view = findViewById(R.id.relativelayout);
                            view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                            Bitmap bitmap = view.getDrawingCache();
                            BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);
                            ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                            iv.setBackgroundDrawable(bitmapDrawable);

                            if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState())) {
                                //we check if external storage is available, otherwise display an error message to the user

                                   File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

                                 //  .getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Indflyt/ "+ inputNr.getText().toString() + ".pdf";
                                   File directory = new File (sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/Indflyt");
                                   directory.mkdirs();

                                   String filename =  inputNr.getText().toString() + "-"+ txtetDate.getText().toString() +".jpg";
                                   File yourFile = new File(directory, filename);

                                   while (yourFile.exists()) {
                                    i++;   
                                    filename = "screenshot" + i + ".jpg"; 
                                    yourFile = new File(directory, filename);
                                   } 

                                   if (!yourFile.exists()) {
                                       if (directory.canWrite())
                                       {
                                           try {
                                             FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(yourFile, true);
                                             bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
                                             out.flush();
                                             out.close();
                                             Toast.makeText(EditProductActivity.this, "Billede gemt i /sdcard/Indflyt/" + inputNr.getText().toString() + "-" + txtetDate.getText().toString() + ".jpg", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                             i++;
                                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                           e.printStackTrace();
                                        }

                                       }
                                   }

                                }
                                else
                                {
                                   Toast.makeText(EditProductActivity.this, "SD Card not available!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }


                    }
                });
```

and my log

```
11-26 11:43:33.413: E/AndroidRuntime(24275): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-26 11:43:33.413: E/AndroidRuntime(24275): Process: com.example.androidhive, PID: 24275
11-26 11:43:33.413: E/AndroidRuntime(24275): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-26 11:43:33.413: E/AndroidRuntime(24275):    at com.example.androidhive.EditProductActivity$6.onClick(EditProductActivity.java:344)
11-26 11:43:33.413: E/AndroidRuntime(24275):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4630)
11-26 11:43:33.413: E/AndroidRuntime(24275):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19340)
11-26 11:43:33.413: E/AndroidRuntime(24275):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
11-26 11:43:33.413: E/AndroidRuntime(24275):    at andrid.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
11-26 11:43:33.413: E/AndroidRuntime(24275):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
11-26 11:43:33.413: E/AndroidRuntime(24275):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5377)
11-26 11:43:33.413: E/AndroidRuntime(24275):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-26 11:43:33.413: E/AndroidRuntime(24275):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-26 11:43:33.413: E/AndroidRuntime(24275):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
11-26 11:43:33.413: E/AndroidRuntime(24275):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
11-26 11:43:33.413: E/AndroidRuntime(24275):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Any help?

Update

```
      View view = findViewById(R.id.relativelayout);
                          view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                          Bitmap bitmap = view.getDrawingCache();
                          ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                          Drawable bitmapDrawable = null;
                          iv.setBackground(bitmapDrawable);
```

Comment: bitmap is apparently null, check http://stackoverflow.com/a/4618030/1967672 , i

Comment: I did made a update, but still the same, could you help a littlet more, I am a little lost here.

Comment: it was because my screenshot was to big, so I removed my scroll view