# Get bitmap of imageview exactly as seen on screen

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview

I want to get exactly the bitmap shown on screen after scale, filtercolor, ... and work with its pixels, for example in order to remove transparent pixels:

```
 for (int y = 0; y < sourceBitmap1.getHeight(); y++) 
        for (int x = 0; x < sourceBitmap1.getWidth(); x++) 
            if (sourceBitmap1.getPixel(x, y) == Color.TRANSPARENT) {
                  //todo do something
            }
```

But it is important to get bitmap related to target Imageview. As I have seen in other posts I can do this with this method:

```
 public static Bitmap loadBitmapFromView(ImageView i) {
    i.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    i.measure(FrameLayout.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0,   FrameLayout.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
            FrameLayout.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0,    FrameLayout.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
    i.layout(0, 0, i.getMeasuredWidth(), i.getMeasuredHeight());
    i.buildDrawingCache(true);
    Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(i.getDrawingCache(true));
    i.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
    return b;
}
```

But why does the method return null?

Comment: tried calling `yourImageView.draw()` ?

Comment: @pskink no ,would you please explain more?

Comment: I mean if you tried to call that method on your ImageView?

Comment: @pskink i do as said on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2339429/android-view-getdrawingcache-returns-null-only-null

Comment: so did you try or you didnt?

Comment: @pskink  think didnt !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Bitmap of ImageView after scaling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38152895/get-bitmap-of-imageview-after-scaling)

Answer (score 0):

try this to get bitmap from imageview

```
 Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) imgview.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
```

Comment: i check this not return scaled bitmap ,this return exacly drawable bitmap consider drawble bitmap is 500*500 but imageview bitmap is 200*200 it return 500*500 drawble