# Get Bitmap of ImageView after scaling

Tags: android, bitmap

I have `ImageView` with a `Bitmap`, and the `ScaleType` is `FitXY` , when I get the `Bitmap` out of the `Imageview`:

```
Bitmap currentBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) context.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
```

the returned is the original `Image` with the original `Width/Height` not the `Scaled Size` , how is it possible to get the `Scaled` `Bitmap` not the original one?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the scaling effects are actually applied at the Canvas level. So, what you can do is get the current Canvas augmentations and then draw your Bitmap into a new one with the changes, BUT, you're going to have to override the ImageView class in order to expose the Matrix that backs the Canvas.

```
public class ExposedImageView extends ImageView {
    protected Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

    ... // constructors

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        canvas.getMatrix(matrix);
    }

    public Matrix getCanvasMatrix(){
        return matrix;
    }
}
```

And then you can get the adjusted image with something like:

```
public static Bitmap getRealImage(ExposedImageView view) throws Throwable { // OutOfMemoryError, etc.
    Bitmap original = ((BitmapDrawable) context.getDrawable())
        .getBitmap();

    Bitmap adjusted = Bitmap.createBitmap(original.getWidth(),
        original.getHeight(), 
        original.getConfig());

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(adjusted);
    canvas.setMatrix(view.getCanvasMatrix());
    canvas.drawBitmap(original, 0, 0, null);

    return adjusted;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer , but `canvas.getMatrix(matrix);` is deprecated, I tried using the `getMatrix()` of the  `ExposedImageView ` , but it's not working!, any suggestions ?

Comment: After digging around a bit more, I'm wondering if the reason View.getMatrix() isn't matching your request could have something to do with https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=24517